# Authenticate two applications using Azure Active Directory

Tags: symfony, azure, saml, saml-2.0

I have a Symfony3 application which is to have a single sign-on relationship with a third party application.

However, the developer of the 3rd party application have rigorous security requirements and have compelled us to use Azure AD for authentication as opposed to out application.

I have configured Azure AD as the IDP and my Application as SP. My question is, how would I be able to have both applications authenticate once through Azure AD because they have difference sign-on urls and subsequent redirect pages.

Comment: Are the apps single- or multitenant? Do the users sign in to the same Azure AD?

Comment: If that's the case, then just have two app. registrations in AAD.

Comment: @juunas The Azure AD APP is multitenant. I'm however new this Azure AD and I haven't come across articles that explain how to levarage on that. The users use the same sign-in on Azure AD

Comment: @nzpcmad How will they share sessions in under such circumstances?

Answer (score 0):

What Azure AD allows is single sign-on. So when a user signs in, they get an active session with Azure AD.

This then means that when you redirect the user to sign in from your app, they will be automatically signed in if they have an active session.

In your case since the app is multi-tenant, the user will be automatically redirected back to your app without needing to login again if they already signed in earlier. Though if they are logged in to multiple accounts at once, Azure AD will require them to choose which account they want to use.